# how to send image file from sd card to jsp using http post request?

Tags: android, jsp, file-upload, android-asynctask

How do we send an image file from sd card to a file or a folder in tomcat server in android?
My server mostly consists of jsp files and no php files. How do we do that? Do we send the request to a jsp file or to a folder? How can a jsp file save an image received to a folder in server?

Answer (score -1):

You should use Base64 to encode the image as a String and send this String to te server and than decoding the String there.

Comment: after decoding the string to a type 'File', how can I save it to a folder or simply beside the jsp file? what should my jsp file look like?

Comment: @migs I don't know how to do that in jsp, but I did in PHP, and that is the way that you should follow, try to search for a tutorial.

Comment: I am now able to encode the image but how can I send it to jsp or php? the string is too large to be sent via post or get. :(